# How do we check last 24 row in database table if $user_id match?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried few experiment but did not work i know also why they not working but i am looking for some way out to do so.

I have table in which i need to check only last 24 row desc order limit 24 if userid is present

I tried this but this is checking only where `user='user_id'`

```
$check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM token WHERE user='$user_id' order by `id` desc limit 24");
if (mysqli_num_rows($check) == 0) {
// not in database
} else {
// yes in database
}
```

And if i remove `WHERE user='$user_id'` then it wont check anything. i am bit confused

```
$check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM token order by `id` desc limit 24");
```

I need to check only last 24 row if `user_id` is present.

[image]

Thanks as always

Comment: Upvoter, care to explain?

Comment: What is in your `$user_id`? Did you run query in MySQL?

Comment: $user_id is among 8000 user in serial number.

Comment: If `id` is user id as you say, you however seem to be comparing `user` with `$user_id`. How can we be sure you are not making a mistake here? Can we have the table, and more description?

Comment: Yes i need to match user_id in new row in table. @ArjunAbhynav

Comment: thee is no such thing like "last 24 rows". Rows in database take no order of their own, but only at select time, if a column to order by were set explicitly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

This will first find last 24 row and then check $user_id if available or not.

```
$check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "select * from (select * from token order by `id` desc limit 24) status where user='$user_id' limit 1");
if (mysqli_num_rows($check) == 0) {
// not in database
} else {
// yes in database
}
```

If help let me know.

Answer (score 0):

When asking a question about SQL query, you need to understand two essential things.

1. You have to omit ALL the useless and unnecessary information like language or driver you are using to call SQL server.
2. You have to provide ALL the required information instead:

   - data structure
   - sample data
   - query
   - desired result

While telling us long story of your wishes would be of little help. We are not jinns. We are programmers.